# Hiding the first value of a number by replacing it with an X in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, hide, substitution, yaxis

I have the code that gives me the following image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
plt.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2],[5004,5006,5002,5007,5001])
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to replace the value of the first number on the y-axis with an X (5001> X001, 5002> X002, and so on).

[image]

Is it possible to do this automatically in matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module.

From the docs:

> The function should take in two inputs (a tick value x and a position pos), and return a string containing the corresponding tick label.

So its just a case of manipulating the tick value, `x`, and changing the first character to an "X".

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], [5004, 5006, 5002, 5007, 5001])

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(
        lambda x, pos: '{}{}'.format('X', str(int(x))[1:])))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: As a convenience, [`set_major_formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html?highlight=set_major_formatter#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter) can take a function directly as its input, which will get converted to a `FuncFormatter` anyway. So, you can avoid the need to import the `ticker` module. You could simplify the example above to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2],[5004,5006,5002,5007,5001])

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: '{}{}'.format('X', str(int(x))[1:]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/dollar_ticks.html) guide from matplotlib and applied it to your example. I found a neat class called [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) that we can use instead of the one in the guide. That class wants a callable that takes `x` and `pos` as arguments which we can do whatever we want with as long as we return a string.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2],[5004,5006,5002,5007,5001])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f"X{str(int(x))[1:]}"))
plt.show()
```

[image: New plot]

Comment: Lol, this looks familiar

Comment: Haha, I was surprised by how similar our answers were. I like your style ;) I concede and upvote you for your neat edit

Comment: tmdavison won because their answer was faster! But thank you Mandera!